# Is this strange sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, literature

> Perhaps nowadays it is our demure contemplation of the Imperfect that
>   the West and the East can meet in mutual consolation.

[Source](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/769/769-h/769-h.htm)

It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because as the OP himself notes, *"It doesn't make sense"*. There is no point in asking us to "analyse" such an invalid sentence.

Comment: As Cees Timmerman suggests below, this is certainly an error, but it is present in the [original](https://archive.org/stream/bookoftea00okakrich#page/n7/mode/2up). You may prefer to read the work in that form, which is much handsomer.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it should be "through our demure..."

Because "our demure contemplation of the Imperfect" isn't something that's meetable.

Comment: How can the East and the West meet "through our demure contemplation"?

Comment: By sharing an activity.

Comment: @user4550 perhaps both :)

Answer (score -1):

At first, I thought this sentence was an example of [it-cleft](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20841/4559), but the resulting sentence after removing the clefting makes no sense:

> That the West and the East can meet in mutual consolation is our demure contemplation of the Imperfect

I cannot imagine how *a meeting of the East and the West* can be *a contemplation*.

This makes me think that a portion of the sentence has been omitted, for example:

> Perhaps nowadays it is our demure contemplation of the Imperfect **[that explains]** that the West and the East can meet in mutual consolation.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker and I don't think it's ungrammatical. Omitting words from a clause is known as ellipsis. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Comment: I don't think you are right on the reasoning. It's simply ungrammatical as the OP said there. For an ellipsis, it's gone a bit too far.